# How do I include spaces in InnerHTML when selecting values from a dropdown list in JavaScript and CSS?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, html-select, innerhtml

How do I include the spaces into the value for InnerHTML ?

So I am selecting a value from a dropdown list, pulling an array list as a Constant in my JS file.

```
const AppleList = ['iPhone 6s' , 'iPhone 7', 'iPhone 7 Plus','iPhone 8' 
                  ,'iPhone X' , 'iPhone Xs' , 'iPhone Xs Max' ,'iPhone Xr','iPhone 11'
                  ,'iPhone 11 Pro','iPhone 11 Pro Max'
                  ,'iPhone 12','iPhone 12 Pro', 'iPhone 12 Pro Max'
                  ,'iPhone 13','iPhone 13 Pro', 'iPhone 13 Pro Max'
                  ,'iPhone 14','iPhone 14 Pro', 'iPhone 14 Pro Max'];

const GoogleList = ['Pixel 3a' , 'Pixel 4'];
const SamsungList = ['S22','S21'];
const ErrorList = ['Select'];
const Repair1List = ['back' , 'front'];
const Repair2List = ['Pixel 3a Screen', 'Pixel 4 Screen'];
const Repair3List = ['S22 Screen', 'S21 Screen'];
const RepairTypeList =['Glass/LCD Screen Repair', 'Housing / Back Glass ', 
                        ' Front Facing Camera', 'Rear Camera', 'Charge Port' ,'Volume Buttons']


function Brand(e)
{
    listselect.innerHTML="";

  if (Brandselect.value == "Apple")
  {
    AppleList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value=${e}">${e}</option>`);
  } 
  else if(Brandselect.value == "Google")
  {
    GoogleList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value=${e}">${e}</option>`);
  }
   else if(Brandselect.value == "Samsung")
  {
    SamsungList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value=${e}">${e}</option>`);
  }
  else
  {
    ErrorList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value=${e}">${e}</option>`);
  }
}
Brandselect.addEventListener('change', Brand);
Brand();



function Model(f)
{
    RepairSelect.innerHTML="";
    
  RepairTypeList.forEach(f => RepairSelect.innerHTML += `<option value=${f}">${f}</option>`)


}
listselect.addEventListener('change', Model);
Model();
```

I posted the photos of the values.
EX: "Iphone" 6".

I need it to be all one string, but not sure how to get the innerHTML to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To include spaces in the value for `innerHTML`, you need to wrap the value in quotes within the HTML tag. Currently, in your code, the value is not wrapped in quotes, which causes issues when the option values contain spaces.

To fix this, modify the following lines of code:

```js
AppleList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value="${e}">${e}</option>`);
```

```js
GoogleList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value="${e}">${e}</option>`);
```

```js
SamsungList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value="${e}">${e}</option>`);
```

```js
ErrorList.forEach(e => listselect.innerHTML += `<option value="${e}">${e}</option>`);
```

```js
RepairTypeList.forEach(f => RepairSelect.innerHTML += `<option value="${f}">${f}</option>`);
```

By adding the double quotes around `${e}` and `${f}`, the spaces in the values will be preserved and included correctly in the HTML output.